Trino not showing Nessie catalog but renaming to iceberg catalog
I'm running iceberg on nessie catalog using spark. Nessie is using postgres DB for persistance.
Docker compose
nessie:
    image: projectnessie/nessie
    container_name: nessie
    ports:
      - "19120:19120"
    environment:
      - QUARKUS_HTTP_PORT=19120
      - QUARKUS_PROFILE=prod
      - QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5435/nessie
      - QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=nessie_user
      - QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=nessie_password
      - NESSIE_VERSION_STORE_TYPE=JDBC
    volumes:
      - ./nessie/data:/var/lib/nessie/data
  nessie-db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    hostname: nessie-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: nessie
      POSTGRES_USER: nessie_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: nessie_password
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    volumes:
      - ./nessie/db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

Data stored in minio s3 warehouse bucket
Spark using env variables
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
MINIO_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyyy
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT=http://minio:9000
WAREHOUSE=s3a://warehouse/
NESSIE_URI=http://nessie:19120/api/v1

Using spark to write to nessie catalog
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os


## DEFINE SENSITIVE VARIABLES
NESSIE_URI = os.environ.get("NESSIE_URI") ## Nessie Server URI
WAREHOUSE = os.environ.get("WAREHOUSE") ## BUCKET TO WRITE DATA TOO
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY") ## AWS CREDENTIALS
AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_KEY") ## AWS CREDENTIALS
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT= os.environ.get("AWS_S3_ENDPOINT") ## MINIO ENDPOINT


print(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT)
print(NESSIE_URI)
print(WAREHOUSE)


conf = (
    pyspark.SparkConf()
        .setAppName('app_name')
        .set('spark.jars.packages', 
             'org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12:1.5.2,'
             'org.projectnessie.nessie-integrations:nessie-spark-extensions-3.3_2.12:0.67.0,'
             'software.amazon.awssdk:bundle:2.17.257,'
             'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.17.257')
        .set('spark.sql.extensions', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions,'
             'org.projectnessie.spark.extensions.NessieSparkSessionExtensions')
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog')
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie.uri', NESSIE_URI)
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie.ref', 'main')
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie.authentication.type', 'NONE')
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie.catalog-impl', 'org.apache.iceberg.nessie.NessieCatalog')
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie.s3.endpoint', AWS_S3_ENDPOINT)
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie.warehouse', WAREHOUSE)
        .set("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "nessie")
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.nessie.io-impl', 'org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO')
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', AWS_SECRET_KEY)
)
## Start Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
print("Spark Running")

#create database
spark.sql("create database if not exists nessie.DB1").show()
# Create a Table
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE if not exists nessie.DB1.test_name2 (name STRING) USING iceberg;").show()
print("Table created")

#Insert
spark.sql("INSERT INTO nessie.DB1.test_name2 VALUES ('name1'), ('name2'), ('name3')").toPandas()
print("Inserted data")

## Query the Data
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM nessie.DB1.test_name2;").show()

This creates a folder DB1 and inside DB1 another folder test_name2 in s3 with data and metadata.
And I can also see the tables in nessie UI.
So far, everything is working as expected. But when I try to query the catalogs, from trino, it is showing iceberg as the catalog name instead of nessie. Inside iceberg catalog, I can find DB1 as the schema name and test_name2 as the table and I can query from trino. But why catalog is named as iceberg instead of nessie.
Trino docker compose
  trino:
    image: $TRINO_IMAGE
    container_name: trino
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      - TRINO_NODE_ID=trino
      - TRINO_DATA_DIR=/data
      - CATALOG_MANAGEMENT=dynamic 
    volumes:
      - ./trino/data:/data
      - ./trino/etc:/etc/trino

Trino dockerfile
# Dockerfile
FROM trinodb/trino:449

# Set environment variables
ENV JAVA_VERSION 22.0.1
# Create necessary directories
RUN mkdir -p /etc/trino/catalog
# Copy configuration files
COPY ./trino/etc/config.properties /etc/trino/
COPY ./trino/etc/jvm.config /etc/trino/
# COPY ./trino/etc/node.properties /etc/trino/
COPY ./trino/etc/log.properties /etc/trino/
COPY ./trino/etc/catalog/iceberg.properties /etc/trino/catalog/

# Set the entrypoint to Trino
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/lib/trino/bin/launcher", "run", "--etc-dir", "/etc/trino"]


iceberg.properties in /etc/trino/catalog/
connector.name=iceberg
iceberg.catalog.type=nessie
iceberg.file-format=PARQUET
iceberg.nessie-catalog.uri=http://host.docker.internal:19120/api/v1
iceberg.nessie-catalog.default-warehouse-dir=s3a://warehouse
iceberg.nessie-catalog.ref=main


fs.native-s3.enabled=true
s3.endpoint=http://host.docker.internal:9000
s3.region=us-east-1
s3.path-style-access=true
s3.aws-access-key=xxx
s3.aws-secret-key=yyyyyy

config.properties
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=50GB
query.max-memory-per-node=8GB
# query.max-total-memory-per-node=10GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://host.docker.internal:8081

other properties defined are log.properties, jvm.config
Once trino container is up, connecting to trino cli via
trino --server host.docker.internal:8081

All the schema and tables inside iceberg is showing correctly but why the catalog name is iceberg and not nessie?
Any pointers?

The catalog name is dictated by the name of the properties file.  I can't seem to find it in the documentation, but rename your iceberg.properties file to nessie.properties if that is the catalog name you want.

Thanks @Tim for the answer.
Yes, after changing iceberg.properties file to nessie.properties. It is working as expected.
